# C# change textbox text on a modal form from an another form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to change a text on a TextBox on a modal main form by clicking on a button from an another active form, need help.

```
Main form *Modal mode

public void changetext(){
  textbox1.text = textnew;
}

form2 *active form

private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   mainform form1 = new mainform;
   public String textnew = "NEW"
   form1.changetext();
   this.close
}
```

Ive tired to use this code but it gives me the error of : Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.:

```
public void LabelWrite(string value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(new LabelWriteDelegate(LabelWrite), value);
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = value;
    }
}
    delegate void LabelWriteDelegate(string value);
```

Comment: Please write a code that compiles

Comment: I think actually is his problem

Comment: sorry im just new here.. im just trying to simplify very long code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there's a logic issue. If i understand your requirement, you have a main form which contains a search textbox. When the user launch a serach, you open a modal form where all possible results are displayed. The user selects the value he wants and then you get the result in the main form. Is this correct? If so you should do it this way:

- Create a public property on the modal form which contains the result.
- Either create a public property or create a new constructor on the modal form to pass the query.
- On the main form, you can access the public properties of the modal form as long as it is not disposed.

For instance:

```
var result = null;
var modal = new ModalForm(query);
if(modal.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // This means the user has selected a value
{
    result = modal.SelectedResult;
}
modal.Close();
modal.Dispose();
```

Comment: Was about to type a similar answer, I would also pass in arguments into the constructor - you can even have multiple constructors if different types are needed.
I have read it's considered bad form (messy) to modify controls directly from other Forms.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass the new text to the modal window.
For example:

*Main form Modal mode*

```
public void changetext(String textnew){
  textbox1.text = textnew;
}
```

*form2 active form*

```
private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           mainform form1 = new mainform;
           form1.changetext("NEW");
           this.close
        }
```

If I were you I would also change form names, they are a little bit confusing.
P.S. I still don't get what is `this.close` is needed for.

Comment: i tried the code but it wont work the text in form1 wont change. Here is the real situation. In form 1 there is a search button and when i click it, form2 will open where i can filter the search in its database. (form2 has its own datagrid for selecting the queried database). Then im gonna select a data in the datagrid then transfer the data to a variable. Then the variable will pass to form1 where i will put the variable's data into form1 textbox at the same time i close form2. and the big problem is that when close form2 form1 didnt change at all..Did you get the idea?...

Comment: BIGGEST PROBLEM 
UI wont update.. checking.. the variables pass is done properly and it work... but textbox in form1 wont change at all..