# Change value of a label in another form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to calculate the discount amount of all the values in another form's `ListBox`, then print that value in both the discount form and the main form.

Discount form code:

```
Private Sub btnCalculateVisit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateVisit.Click

    Dim dblVisits As Double = 0

    If (IsNumeric(txtVisits.Text)) Then

        If txtVisits.Text >= 0 And txtVisits.Text <= 3 Then
            dblVisits = (dblVisitRates(0) * GlobalVariables.price)

        ElseIf txtVisits.Text >= 4 And txtVisits.Text <= 8 Then
            dblVisits = (dblVisitRates(1) * GlobalVariables.price)

        ElseIf txtVisits.Text >= 9 And txtVisits.Text <= 13 Then
            dblVisits = (dblVisitRates(2) * GlobalVariables.price)

        ElseIf txtVisits.Text >= 14 And txtVisits.Text <= 1000000 Then
            dblVisits = (dblVisitRates(3) * GlobalVariables.price)

        End If

    End If

    lblDiscountAmount.Text = "$" + dblVisits.ToString

End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click

    Dim main As New MainForm()

    main.lblDisRate.Text = GlobalVariables.dblType.ToString

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

The calculation prints out on the discount form, but doesn't change the label in the main form. How do i do this?

Comment: Create a method on the "main form" to accept the info, pass the data.

Comment: The code in `btnClose_Click` is not updating the label in your main form. It is creating a new copy of the main form (which is never shown), updating the label in that copy, and then allowing it to be closed.

Comment: I added the update code to the btnClose_Click sub and it still shows nothing.. main.lblDisRate.Text = GlobalVariables.disRate.ToString
        main.lblDisRate.Update()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# change textbox text on a modal form from an another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449818/c-sharp-change-textbox-text-on-a-modal-form-from-an-another-form)

Answer (score 0):

try it with the caption property and do a refresh to the form.

```
lblDiscountAmount.Caption = "$" + dblVisits.ToString
Me.refresh
```